# Relation between the sheaf of relative differentials and the canonical divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $\hspace{0.2cm}f:$ $X\longrightarrow Y \hspace{0.2cm}$ be a finite morphism of curves over $K$.
Consider $\hspace{0.2cm}\Omega_{X/K}\hspace{0.2cm}$ and $\hspace{0.2cm}\Omega_{Y/K}\hspace{0.2cm}$ the sheaves of relative differentials:
why and in what sense do they represent the canonical divisors of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Because the canonical divisor of $X$ is defined to be the divisor associated to the line bundle $\Omega_{X/K}$. If you have a different definition, you should add it to the post.